# is there an jQuery function to less my code

Tags: javascript, jquery

**[My jQuery code is to long to this   ]**

[image: here is image]

```
    $('.about').mouseenter(function(){
      $(this).css({'transform':'translateY(-32px)','transition':'0.5s','color':'rgb(202, 157, 117)'})})
        $('.about').mouseleave(function(
    {$(this).css({'transform':'translateY(0px)','transition':'0.5s','color':'rgb(249, 240, 236)'})})

    $('.progress').mouseenter(function(){
          $(this).css({'transform':'translateY(-32px)','transition':'0.5s','color':'rgb(202, 157, 117)'})})
            $('.progress').mouseleave(function(
        {$(this).css({'transform':'translateY(0px)','transition':'0.5s','color':'rgb(249, 240, 236)'})})
```

Comment: First Approach: Create two _CSS classes_ in your style file, and then _attach_ those CSS classes to your _events_.
Another Approach: Create CSS class, let say ```button``` with same properties you have on mouse enter, and another class ```button:a``` with mouseleave properties, and then apply ```button``` class on your **about** and **progress** HTML tag.

Comment: By "*less*" do you mean *reduce*?  Rather than less.js ?

Comment: The comment from H.S alludes to : https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Comment: *My code is [too] long* - see [mcve] - reduce it to the minimum that demonstrates your issue (which it looks like you've done, but wanted to refer you to that page for future reference)